# Scala: can I get access to the type of a typed method?

Tags: scala, methods, implicit, typed

I'm writing a DSL and I have a situation where'd I'd like a value to be implicitly converted to any type.  I've created a wrapper class with the value and an implicit method that mostly works:

```
case class ObjectOperationResult( val value: AnyRef )

object ObjectOperationResult {
    implicit def result2T[ T ]( result: ObjectOperationResult ): T = {
        result.value.asInstanceOf[ T ]
    }
}
```

The code will throw an exception if result.value isn't a valid type; it's up to the user to make sure they're doing the right thing.  However, I'd like to make it smarter by executing different logic depending on the target type.  For example, if the target type is String call toString instead of asInstanceOf[]; something like this:

```
case class ObjectOperationResult( val value: AnyRef )

object ObjectOperationResult {
    implicit def result2T[ T ]( result: ObjectOperationResult ): T = {
        match T {
            case String s: result.value.toString
            case _ : result.value.asInstanceOf[ T ]
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile; is there any way to determine the type of T so I can act accordingly?

Answer (score -1):

You can define multiple functions, like

```
object ObjectOperationResult {
    implicit def toString( result: ObjectOperationResult ): String =  result.value.toString.trim
    implicit def toInt( result: ObjectOperationResult ): Int = result.value.asInstanceOf[Int]
}
```

This approach is better, for some reasons:
1. You code will compile only with correct types. Compile errors are always better, then runtime errors
2. You can call this function explicitly. This may be very important, if you'll call this code from Java.

Comment: That's currently what I do.  The problem is that it can't handle all possibilities.  For example, the user might want to use their own class.  If possible I'd like a solution that can handle any class.

Comment: `val str=ObjectOperationResult("foo"); val i=str` this will compile as implicit conversion `ObjectOperationResult => Int` is provided by `ObjectOperationResult.toInt` but will fail as runtime due to the cast `anyRefValyeOfStr.asInstanceOf[Int]`. Not compile-time safe.

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this is to pass the class type as an argument and condition on that.

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._

case class ObjectOperationResult( val value: AnyRef )

object ObjectOperationResult {
    def result2T[T: TypeTag](c: Class[T], result: ObjectOperationResult): T = {
        c match {
            case s if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[String] => result.value.toString.asInstanceOf[T]
            case _ => result.value.asInstanceOf[T]
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how you can use this:

```
val a = ObjectOperationResult("hello")
val b = ObjectOperationResult(new java.util.Date())

ObjectOperationResult.result2T(classOf[String], a)
res0: String = hello

ObjectOperationResult.result2T(classOf[String], b)
res1: String = Fri Jul 03 13:15:12 PDT 2015

ObjectOperationResult.result2T(classOf[java.util.Date], b)
res2: java.util.Date = Fri Jul 03 13:15:12 PDT 2015
```